# Google Cloud SQL Maintenance Window

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

The reason I'm hesitating between RDS and Cloud SQL is that I couldn't find that if I set a Cloud SQL instance to high availability with read replicas how will the scheduled maintenances happen. After reading SO and documentation for quite a few hours now I believe that even in case of a HA instance you can experience outages due to scheduled maintenance, so you cannot set any settings / policies to have virtually 100% uptime unlike in AWS RDS where you can set different maintenance windows for replicas.

Am I right? If not, how to achieve the same as in AWS? If I am, what's the rationale behind this behaviour? How are you even supposed to move your service to GCP if you can't guarantee it being always accessible? What's even the point of HA if it also has downtimes?

Comment: This document covers maintenance windows: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/maintenance for MySQL. There is a similar document for each DB. Edit your question to specify what type of events. Some events require downtime, some do not.

Comment: Design your services to handle downtime. There are no services that provide 100% uptime. There is always a small window no matter how much you spend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

**Edit**

I haven't personally experienced this myself but based on Stefan G's pointer, there has been [open issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111521234) with Google Cloud SQL which despite having HA which caused downtime during maintenance window:

---

High availability equates to multi-az sql instance. So when you set this option you get a primary instance running in a zone and secondary in another zone. So when maintenance window kicks in the cloud sql *should* automatically fail over to the other availability zone and your app / users shouldn't be affected. However there are some reported incidents where Cloud SQL caused a downtime (see edit notes below).

Read-replicas on the other hand helps you offload traffic from your master instance it does not give you redundancy.

No hosted SQL offers 100% uptime guarantee. RDS Aurora offers 99.99%. Cloud SQL on the other hand offers 99.95% uptime guarantee, which equates to downtime of no more than Daily: 43.2s. Weekly: 5m 2.4s. Monthly: 21m 54.9s.

We use Cloud SQL and it's reliable enough and upgrades during maintenance window are seamless.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! So in your experience maintenance gets done on failover instances and THEN on the master, and another one gets promoted to master, or it's not guaranteed? Maxim's answer states this but it applies to read replicas only.

Comment: Maintenance sequence is not guaranteed for failover instance. Why do you think the upgrade sequence matters?

Comment: I didn't mean that I care about the order of upgrades, only about that I have at least one working instances at all times during planned maintenances (given that I have HA turned on of course), so an upgrade on the master is only initiated if there's an instance to fail over to.

Comment: Good point, to my understanding, as long as the failover instance is in the other availability zone then the update should take place in sequential manner, yes. I'll try to find some reference doc regarding this and update my answer.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm afraid that the accepted answer is not correct. At least the first paragraph. It seems you are considering that a read replica gets promoted during a maintenance window and that does not work like that. A failover occurs when an instance is unhealthy a maintenance occurs during the specified or not window. In the second "here" link that @Maxim posted you can read and understand that maintenance can disrupt service even with HA.

As you accepted Parth Mehta message I assume that is your understanding of how Cloud SQL behaves, but Maxim's answer is correct.

Comment: In summary: even though you have HA,maintenance can occur and disrupt your service even for a short time. In this link[1] people are discussing specifically this.

Hope this helps.

[1]: https://issuetracker.google.com/111521234

Comment: @stefan that's interesting, we have been using Cloud SQL for 9 months which have gone through at least 2 (may be 3 major maintenances but it didn't cause downtime. But I'll update my answer accordingly to cover for the case mentioned in the issue tracker so people can do due diligence before considering CloudSQL.

Comment: I wanted to clarify that it can happen, not that it will always happen. His main worry was having any downtime and I think it's fair to let him know and that Google is working on it.

Thank you for editing it Parth.

Comment: Thank you for posting comment about this, it was helpful.

Comment: This is a misleading answer. As of today Cloud SQL does not support zero downtime
and [according to Google](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/how-cloud-sql-maintenance-works-to-keep-instances-updated), maintenance downtime can range from 30 to 120 seconds depending on SQL vendor. There's an open issue about supporting zero downtime: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111521234

Answer (score 3):

Read replicas neither provide High Availability nor offer it, and I'm afraid they do not support the maintenance window either. This is explained in the [Cloud SQL FAQs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/tips#rr-info) among other information.

There are Feature Requests opened on the Public Issue Tracker regarding this [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/124683217) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/111521234) - you may show your interest by clicking on the *star* button.

When scheduled maintenance occurs, the operations are first performed on the read replica(s) and then on the master instance. Cloud SQL *attempts* to keep one of them running at all time, but this is not guaranteed, is subject to change and you shouldn't rely on it.

If availability is that critical for you, you are better off using [Cloud Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/) instead, which offers a 99.999% availability SLA.

Answer (score 0):

GCP has pretty good documentation on the steps of maintenance.
HA is only for unplanned outrage

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/maintenance#pre-maintenance